# Pooling data from n groups with different means and variances; finding the standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, sample, pooling

I want to pool data from different samples, each with a different mean, standard deviation and n. I don't have the original data, only these three parameters.I'm sure they can be pooled because they belong to the same population (but with different time sampling) and that they are non-overlapping.
Figuring out the mean is simple, but I'm having problems with the standard deviation.

Most links on this forum provide answers for finding mean and variance of POPULATIONS but I would like the formula for SAMPLE-based statistics, so with denominator n-1.

For this I found [Wikipedia Sample-based statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Sample-based_statistics). I believe I can reduce the formula for the standard deviation of non overlapping populations to the one given in [Wikipedia Pooled Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance), except for the denominator! The denominator for the first one is $(\sum_{i=1}^k n_i) - 1$ while for the second is $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i-1$, which gives an entire different result, with the first giving me lower results. Perhaps this is because on the second formula it is assumed that "the variance of each population is the same", but I would like to understand it mathematically to know which is correct.

(Also, my n are two small to assume normality of samples)

Comment: Welcome! Please check that I interpreted your formulas correctly.

Comment: I'm looking at the two hyperlinks, and wondering if the issue is simply the word "sub-samples" under *sample-based statistics*. The entry goes on to say that for "the more general case of M non-overlapping data sets,..." the pooled variance would have $\sum_i N_{X_i} - 1$, which would be concordant with $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i-1$.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Thank you for your input. Just to make sure I understand you: You are saying that for the "M non overlapping data sets"  the denominator is Sum(Nx-1), as in the pooled variance (and resulting in "n1+n2+n3+...nk-k". Is this correct?